# Can the folder have no name in Ubuntu ?

Tags: directory

I have a folder in my system with no name in it. It is empty. But that folder has files inside it.

Just out of curiosity, I tried to create another folder and try to rename it by not giving any name. But I could not do it.

Any idea, how can it be achieved?

On the same topic, how to access that folder in the shell?

Comment: If you do `ls -l` in the parent directory, what is the output?

Comment: I am sorry, in the height of excitement, I renamed it to "/". I was trying to use the escape sequence "\ " ( Read it as \<space> )

Comment: I could create a folder called " " (space) just typing `mkdir " "`. It had name, just that it was named " "

Comment: @Braiam, Vow, Thanks, Any idea, how do we access in the terminal?

Comment: `cd \ /` works just fine

Answer (score 3):

Accourding with these [Rules For Naming File And Directory Names](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/), no, it can't have no name, but can be named with one or more space/blank characters:

[image]

---

[image]

From the above picture you can deduce that you can access a directory having only a space in the name with:

```
cd ' '
```

Comment: For example `mkdir ''` returns `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory` or `mkdir -p some//path` just create `some/path`.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, but for example `mkdir ' '` is creating a `' '` directory :/

Comment: Sorry, I was under the perception you have read [my other comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/330569/can-the-folder-have-no-name-in-ubuntu/330578?noredirect=1#comment420510_330569)